# Edit Power BI pbiviz custom visual package

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I'm looking for editing a custom visual I found in the internet (its tooltip shows some data I'd like to hide).

I found out that the `pbiviz` file is actually a [zipped folder](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Editting-an-existing-Custom-Visual/td-p/137025), I extracted it and got a `package.json` and a folder with another `.json` containing the source code of the visual. The source code is minified, but I managed to make the fix there.

Now I don't know how to pack the `pbiviz` file again. I tried to zip the folder and rename it to `.pbiviz`, but Microsoft Power BI tell me it "isn't a valid custom visual" (I tried it also without editing, the error message is the same, what makes me conclude this isn't the right way to package it).

I'm trying to use [Microsoft developing tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals) to build this package, but I still couldn't make it work.

**TL;DR**: I need help to edit a `pbiviz` source code, package it back and use on Power BI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of zipping back, you can keep the original `.pbviz` file, open it with a software like `7-zip` and replace the files you need. This way, Power BI still recognizes it like a valid custom visual.

**Important**: it's necessary to replace the `guid` in every file for a new one, otherwise your fix will be replaced by the version on marketplace.